# How to make faster readable elements from the list?

Tags: list, development, asp.net, performance, query

I have an ASP Calendar, which shows elements from the list. If I try to bind the elements to the list, there are a lot of elements for example 35 429 elements. It takes up to 4 minutes to load this webpart after refresh.

I put Callendar on Ajax and Update Panel. When it reads once the calendar change fast, until next refresh.

Please tell me how make it faster?

Maybe I should work with paging in a calendar, to read from list faster?

Please how can I query faster, becouse 4 minutes are not acceptable, and in short time I will have to put 360 000 elements, which will probably take up to 40 minutes to load...

Please help.

Comment: Why would you need to show 360 000 elements to a user... that's not usefull. Maybe try working with paging?

Comment: But how add pagging to the ASP Calendar ?

Comment: Is this 2007 or 2010?

Comment: It's a 2010 version.

Answer (score 0):

360,000 items is unmanageable for a human to sit there and read, especially in a calendar view. What's your end goal or requirements for this? Do you really need all of them there or are you looking for some reporting/summarization of the data?

Writing the items to the page will be slow because there's a lot of data to process AND the resulting HTML output is going to be large. So regardless of improving the code behind it to improve the speed, the client still has to download, what I would imagine, is a relatively large HTML file (speaking in average web page sizes).

Where are your items living? Are they in a SharePoint list or SQL?

Comment: Because I have one list's with ranges DataStart, and Data Stop and secound list with describing in details first list. Element by element. And i present it's list on calendar. So it maybe will have got 360 000 element's in year. The item's Living on a List, because I think I will must use a infopath to describe elements. Please help, how to add pagging to a ASP Calendar.

Comment: At Sharepoint List